# IntelliJ can not run Jest test (green arrow button)

Tags: angular, windows, intellij-idea, jestjs

When I run or debug a Jest test in IntelliJ IDEA by clicking the green arrow
[image] I get this error:

[image]

The same configuration works for my collegues and I can run the test manually.

My projects root directory is `p:\src\foobar`, where `p:\` is mounted with `subst p: c:\p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the solution is to use `c:\p\...` as root directory and not NTFS mounts like `p:\...`